# creating a variable number of variables and populating them from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to create a few variables at the same time.

I want the user to specify a value and as a result create that many unique variables, populate them with values from an already created list and then print the results.

I can do this if I specify the number of variables each time, but I want the program to ask the user for the number instead.

This works as I would like; but, it assumes I know the number of Hands to create

```py
Deck = ["AC","AH","AS","AD","KC","KH","KS","KD"]
Hand1 = [Deck.pop(),Deck.pop()]
Hand2 = [Deck.pop(),Deck.pop()]
...
HandN = [Deck.pop(),Deck.pop()]

print("Hand1: ", Hand1)
print("Hand2: ", Hand2)
...
print("HandN: ", HandN)
```

I want to do the same but instead ask the user for how many hands to create, Something like:

```py
Deck = ["AC","AH","AS","AD","KC","KH","KS","KD"]
NumberOfHands = int(input("How Many Hands? "))

for each in range(1,NumberOfHands+1):
    Hand+str(each) = [DeckList.pop(),DeckList.pop]

for each in range(1,NumberOfHands+1):
    print(Hand+str(each))
```

The way I thought this would have worked results in a syntax error.

I've seen some other questions that look similar and hint at doing this with a dictionary; but, its not making sense to me on how to apply it for this type of scenario...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any time you think you want to create a bunch of variables with names like `HandN`, create a list `hand` instead and access it via `N` -- `hand[0]`, `hand[1]`, ...etc.

Comment: I think the main issue is trying to define the "Hand+str(each)" variable - you can't construct them like that! As @MarkMeyer mentioned you can construct a list of "Hand"s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it with a dict:

```
hands = {f"Hand{each + 1}": [Deck.pop(), Deck.pop()] for each in range(NumberOfHands)}
```

This will create a dict of size `NumberOfHands` containing all the hands from `1` to `NumberOfHands`

Comment: This works, I think it also potions me best by putting the data in a good format to use forward.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> You can do it

## **But you shuldn't**

```
Deck = ["AC","AH","AS","AD","KC","KH","KS","KD"]
NumberOfHands = int(input("How Many Hands? "))
for n in range(1,NumberOfHands+1):
  globals()["Hand" + str(n)] = [Deck.pop(),Deck.pop()]

for n in range(1,NumberOfHands+1):
    print( globals()['Hand{}'.format(n)])
```

example:

```
How Many Hands? 4
['KD', 'KS']
['KH', 'KC']
['AD', 'AS']
['AH', 'AC']
```

this is a dirty approach of how to do it, but seriously, consider to create only one variable and store them in a list, and access them by index, something safer.

Consider this nice blog to read: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html

Comment: Thank you for the blog reference; it was a good read.  I really appreciate too that you showed the dirty solution, for this case as I think it over more putting my lists of hands into a dictionary will make most sense for how I want the program to interact with them later.  This is a great answer even if its not the one I'm going to actually use.  Thanks!